# Plotting a given timestamp from Database in JFreeChart x axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am getting the values from a database which is of `Timestamp` datatype. I am now trying to plot the timestamp values in the xxaxis in Jfreechart. Currently I am using

`final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series1", Millisecond.class);`

I am confused in adding the timestamp values to the time series. The timestamp values are in the following format.

> 2013-07-22 17:10:49.219

Can anyone please help me? I have referred many sites. In some sites they have suggested to extract the date, hours, minutes, and milliseconds to add  in the series. But from timestamp how should I extract the values? I am new to this topic and the Date functions are really confusing for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamp is a subclass of the java.util.Date class, so for a TimeSeries in JFreeChart you can directly create a Millisecond instance using this constructor:

```
 public Millisecond(Date time);
```

Your code will look something like this (assuming s1 is your TimeSeries instance):

```
 TimeStamp t = ... // read from somewhere
 double value = ... // the data value associated with your timestamp
 s1.add(new Millisecond(t), value);
```

...looping around of course to handle all your data items.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks David Gilbert for your answer.
I was not entirely successful or maybe I just misunderstood you but Millisecond needs a Date as Parameter.
Anyway: the following code works for me.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  public MyFrame() {
    XYDataset xyData = createDataset();
    JFreeChart timeSeriesChart = 
    ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("name of chart",
    "X-axis-name", "y-axis-name", xyData);

    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(timeSeriesChart);
    MainPane.add(panel);
    this.pack();
  }

private XYDataset createDataset() {
        TimeSeries timeSeries = new TimeSeries("valueVsTime");

        // loop start
        long timeStamp = ...//read from somewhere, on x axis
        double value = ...//read from somewhere, on y axis
        timeSeries.add(new Millisecond(new Date(timeStamp), value));
        // loop end

        TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);
        return dataset;
    }
}
```